# Sharing folders between Ubuntu computers fails

Tags: 11.10, samba, sharing

I am attempting to share files between two computers running 11.10. I'm using the built-in samba sharing. When I try to mount the files on another computer it says "Failed to mount Windows share". I have no clue how to get this working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I went through the guide and now nothing shows up in my network. I followed the instructions as it said.

Comment: What is the output from: **smbclient -L localhost -U%**

Comment: Why are you using Samba (Windows file handling) for 'share' of files between two computers with Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through the Ubuntu Documentation page for [setting up Samba File Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html).

It's pretty comprehensive and should give you all the answers you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading to 11.10, my access t0 samba share was using a DNS alias. workaround was to use the real hostname; may be a bug with smbclient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point using Samba to share files between Linux machines! Samba is meant for accessing *Windows* network shares and services.

Use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) instead, there is no setup necessary at all:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Mount the remote filesystem with

```
sshfs user@host:/path /local/mount/point
```

and unmount with

```
fusermount -u /local/mount/point
```